# firebase.auth().createCustomToken is undefined on web app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a "remember me" function for my web app that uses Firebase.

My goal is that when a user clicks "remember me" and logs in successfully, their authentication token is stored using localStorage and they are logged in automatically on their next visit (I prefer this to storing their raw credentials in localStorage for security purposes).

However, when I tried to call `firebase.auth().createCustomToken` I got an error saying it does not exist. Is this the wrong approach or the wrong function call for firebase? Thanks!

Here is a sample of my code:

```
var customToken = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(user.uid);
localStorage.setItem("savedToken", customToken);
```

then later I plan to use this line to sign back in:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(localStorage.getItem("savedToken")).then(function() {
```

Comment: Please show your code. It's much easier to debug when we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 7):

[`firebase.auth().createCustomToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_sdk) is only available in the server API.

To authenticate with an email & password and get the token for the session, try this:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(function(user) {
    user.getToken().then(function(token) {
      localStorage.setItem("savedToken", token); // store the token
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle error...
  });
```

This will work with the other authentication methods, too; just use [`User.getToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User#getToken). Later, if you have a token (still on the client), and you want to authenticate with it, <s>just do what you are currently doing:</s>

```
var token = localStorage.getItem("savedToken"); // get stored token
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
  // handle error...
});
```

*The above code doesn't work, because `signInWithCustomToken` only works for tokens minted by your server with `createCustomToken`. I'm not sure how to auth with an email/password token.*

Comment: Thank you but that is actually old documentation and unfortunately very little of this code works for Firebase 3.0 and above (which is what I'm using).

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. Is this what you want to do though?

Comment: @LiorHirschfeld Edited for Firebase 3.x

Comment: Thank you, I think this might have fixed the error of getting the custom token assigned to the user but I still cannot use it to login as I get the error "The custom token format is incorrect" when I use your exact code from above. Any idea what the problem could be? (I'm pretty sure that the token assignment to local storage is working properly as when I log the token upon login attempt I get a seemingly randomized string of characters).

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, but before posting, are you using Firebase's email/password authentication?

Comment: Yes I am, my first line is just as your wrote above.

Comment: Well, apparently `signInWithCustomToken` only works with tokens minted on your server with `createCustomToken`. I'm not sure how to auth with an email/password token... maybe [`signInWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithCredential), but I'm not sure how to get a `Credential` from a token.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a custom token requires having access to the private key/service account of your Firebase project. This key is the master key to gaining access to a Firebase project, knowing it gives unlimited access.

Since someone knowing the private key has unlimited access to the Firebase project, it makes no sense to *ever* mint custom tokens on the client. You might as simply remove all security from your Firebase database and storage services.

To authenticate a client using a custom token, [mint a custom token on an app server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens) and pass that (securely) to the client. Then [use the custom on the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) with `signInWithCustomToken`. This way only your app server has to know the service account/private key.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know to sign in using the getToken() method, which is what I was originally aiming for? My ultimate goal is to allow the user to login again without locally storing their username and password - is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The user's current token is automatically stored when the user signs in and restored when they revisit. It sounds like you're missing an `onAuthStateChanged` handler: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: Thanks, but I tried running the line "var user = firebase.auth().currentUser" after my page loaded and I always got the result that no user was logged in, even if one had been logged in before the page was refreshed. Do you know why the current token is not being restored?

Comment: That's why I said `onAuthStateChanged` and not `currentUser` ;-)
Firebase uses a mix of short-lived access tokens and long lived ID tokens. Most likely the access token needs to be refreshed.